# MS Access: How do I restrict a table from reducing in size?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, integrity, linked-tables

I have a DB with 2 tables. One is linked to by 50 different laptops and they are all appending to this table. To prevent accidents, I am having the data in the linked-to table overwrite the contents of the other table.

But what if a malicious user opens up the linked-to table and deletes everything? I want Access to **not** blank out the other table as well. Is there a way to restrict a table from ever reducing in size (number of rows)? Is this even a good way to protect my data?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to restrict a table from ever reducing in size (number
>   of rows)?

With an Access database, your options are limited.

If you use the older MDB format for your database, you could then set up user-level security to deny `DELETE` privilege on the table for a defined group of users.

With either ACCDB or MDB format, you could add a `CHECK` constraint to ensure the table's row count can not drop below a target number --- but then you would need to adjust that target number as the table grows, which means dropping the old constraint and adding the new constraint version.

With Access 2010, you might be able to use a data macro to cancel deletes (I haven't investigated that possibility), but that approach would definitely not work for Access 2007.

If protecting the data is important enough, I suggest you migrate the table to a more powerful database system, such as SQL Server, and revoke `DELETE` privilege on the table.

Comment: Hans is right. With this amount of activity and security requirements, an Access database is not the right tool. The _Express_ version of _SQL Server_ is free to install and use.